# Mysql: how to handle tables with millions of rows?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-performance

I'm looking for solutions to properly archive very large tables (about 10,000 rows per day).

I currently have this situation:

**Order Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idproduct` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `iduser` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `progressive` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `show-voucher` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `voucher-custom` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  `check-validate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `code-order` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `code-product` char(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product-year` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2017',
  `product-area` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `payment-type` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usr-qnt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usr-id` char(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usr-cid` char(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usr-ct` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000',
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-penale` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-rate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-contanti` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-bonusmalus-rate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-bonusmalus-contanti` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price-incasso-contanti` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `rate-qnt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `card-qnt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `grp-user` longtext NOT NULL,
  `grp-price` longtext NOT NULL,
  `grp-item` longtext NOT NULL,
  `grp-element` longtext NOT NULL,

  `bonusmalus-description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,

  `note-s` text NOT NULL ,
  `note-c` text NOT NULL,
  `note-incasso` text NOT NULL,
  `note-interne` text NOT NULL,

  `d-start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `d-end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `d-create` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-incasso` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `d-sconf` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-cconf` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-export` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-expire` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-notify-vote` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `d-lastupdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `iduser` (`iduser`),
  KEY `code-order` (`code-order`),
  KEY `code-product` (`code-product`),
  KEY `idproduct` (`idproduct`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `price` (`price`),
  KEY `usr-qnt` (`usr-qnt`),
  KEY `d-expire` (`d-expire`),
  KEY `d-export` (`d-export`),
  KEY `price-bonusmalus-contanti` (`price-bonusmalus-contanti`),
  KEY `price-penale` (`price-penale`),
  KEY `price-bonusmalus-contanti_2` (`price-bonusmalus-contanti`),
  KEY `price-rate` (`price-rate`),
  KEY `price-contanti` (`price-contanti`),
  KEY `show-voucher` (`show-voucher`),
  KEY `voucher-custom` (`voucher-custom`),
  KEY `check-validate` (`check-validate`),
  KEY `progressive` (`progressive`),
  KEY `d-incasso` (`d-incasso`),
  KEY `price-incasso-contanti` (`price-incasso-contanti`),
  KEY `d-notify-vote` (`d-notify-vote`),
  KEY `product-year` (`product-year`),
  KEY `product-area` (`product-area`),
  KEY `d-lastupdate` (`d-lastupdate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Orders are the requests that users (**iduser**) make for tourist packages, such as **Booking.com**

This table generates about **8,000** to **15,000** lines per day.
I'm afraid this table may become too big and cause problems.

My core fields are:

- **id** or **code-order**
- **Idproduct** or **product code** (I have about 5000 products each year)
- **Iduser**
- **Product year** (I have different products for each year)
- **Product area** (I have a total of 20 areas: 000, 001, 002, 003 ... 019)

I've read several solutions on the web, but I can not figure out which one might be the best one:

**1) Divide the main table into many other sub-tables or many other databases?**

Ex.

- Db-2016.tbl_order-jan
- Db-2016.tbl_order-feb
- .....
- Db-2017.tbl_order-jan
- Db-2017.tbl_order-feb

**Or**

- Db.tbl_order-2016
- Db.tbl_order-2015
- Db.tbl_order-2014

**Or**

- Db.tbl_order-master
- Db.tbl_order-product-area

**Or**

- Db.tbl_order-master
- Db.tbl_order-product-year

In this case, are SELECTs to be made through the UNION?

**2) Partition the table?**
Which fields can be performing?
Product year? Product area (Total 20)?
The date of creation of the order (d-create)?
By id?

**3) Sharding? But I do not know what it is ...**

**4) Innodb o MyISAM?**

One solution I can still adopt is also to split the LONGTEXT fields into secondary tables to reduce the weight of tbl_order:

- Db.tbl_order
- Db.tbl_order-grp-user (idorder, data)
- Db.tbl_order-grp-price (idorder, data)
- Db.tbl_order-grp-item (idorder, data)
- Db.tbl_order-grp-element (idorder, data)

**Doubt:** If I do this I have reduced the weight of the tbl_order table, but I have not reduced the number of records. Therefore the *db.tbl_order-grp-user, db.tbl_order-grp-price, db.tbl_order-grp-item, db.tbl_order-grp-elements* tables must be partitioned? If you are using range idorder?

**The SELECT to have all the data will be:**

```
Select *,
( SELECT `u`.`data` FROM `db`.`tbl_order-grp-user` as `u` where `u`.`idorder`=`order`.`id`) as `grp-user`, 
( SELECT `p`.`data` FROM `db`.`tbl_order-grp-price` as `p` where `p`.`idorder`=`order`.`id`) as `grp-price`, 
( SELECT `i`.`data` FROM `db`.`tbl_order-grp-item` as `i` where `i`.`idorder`=`order`.`id`) as `grp-item`
FROM  `db`.`tbl_order` as `order`
WHERE ............
```

Thanks for all the support! :-)

Comment: 15000 rows per day is a small database, not a large one by any standard. I suggest you concentrate on building and testing functionality and don't worry too much about storage optimisation at this early stage.

Answer (score 3):

Novice alert...

Don't use `INT` (4 bytes) when `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes) would suffice.  Look up the rest of the `INT` options.

Don't blindly index every column.

Do look at your `SELECTs` to see which *composite* indexes would be beneficial.  See my [*Index Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .

Don't worry much about 15K/day -- that is less than 1/sec.  100/sec is the first tipping point toward *potential* problems.

Don't `PARTITION`.  It is *not* a panacea, and usually provides no benefits.  There are very few use cases.

Don't split into multiple 'identical' tables.  Ever.  (Well, there are very few valid use cases.)

Don't fear a million rows; do have concern about a billion rows.

Don't use `CHAR` for variable length fields; use `VARCHAR`.

Do consider utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  utf8mb4 matches the external world's view of `UTF-8`, and includes Emoji and all of Chinese.

Do use InnoDB.  Period.  Full stop.  MyISAM is going away; InnoDB is as good or better in virtually all respects.

Consider changing the column names to avoid `-`; `_` is common, and avoids errors when you forget the backtics.

Don't Shard.  (This is splitting the data across multiple servers.)  This is a medium sized table with medium sized traffic; Sharding is need for huge tables with huge traffic.

Do say `CHARACTER SET ascii` where appropriate.  For example `product-area`.  What you have now takes 9 bytes -- 3 characters * room for 3 bytes (utf8) per character.

Consider `TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` for `product-area` -- This will take 1 byte and reconstruct the leading zeros for you.

Consider whether you have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY` instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Do tell us what the `grp` columns contain.

Do come back with tentative `SELECT` statements.  I cannot finish this review without them.

Do consider whether this should be a single table.  Is it really the case that one user orders exactly one product?  You probably need a table for users, a table for products, a table for orders, etc.

Comment: Good review, even though I don't fully agree here (e.g. mixing charsets in a single table is calling for trouble).

Comment: @MikeLischke - Please elaborate on why two different columns with different charsets is asking for trouble.  (I can't think of how it could.)  A simple use case:  name in utf8mb4 and country_code in ascii.